# How to add keyword for SEO in homepage in Drupal site through CMS?

Tags: drupal-7, meta-tags

I want to add metatags and keyword in home page in header section.

I am not able to find the correct place from where I can add keywords and metatags through Dashboard (CMS).

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t want to edit your theme (you could, for example, output the value of a hidden field), you may want to use a module.

https://groups.drupal.org/node/18941 is a comparison of meta tag modules (but it was last updated in 2012).

For Drupal 7, popular/stable modules seem to be [**Metatag**](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) and [**Meta tags quick**](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatags_quick). [Both support tokens](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/105367/9223), so you could use the value of an already existing field if you prefer.

Comment: sir is there any way add meta tags through dashboard

Comment: Do you really mean the Dashboard, or do you mean the backend in general (e.g., somewhere in the editing interface)? In the latter case, the modules I linked to allow you to add metatags from the editing interface.